# Auto-closing functionality on Twitter Bootstrap JS alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The Twitter Bootstrap library now has Javascript plugins available, and one of them is supposed to give your alerts an automatic close button.

The documentation is [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts)

I can't figure out how to get it to work. See this code and fiddle:

```
<div class = "alert-message fade in" data-alert = "alert">
    <p>This is an alert!</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBQcp/

I'm sure there's a syntax piece that I'm missing, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alerts are not supposed to be auto-closed because the intention is to the user to notice any message before closing.

Although you can add a link so the user can close it manually this way.

```
<div class = "alert-message fade in" data-alert = "alert">
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>

  <p>This is an alert!</p>
</div>
```

Or can be closed programatically this way:

```
$(".alert-message").alert('close')
```

Comment: sorry, by auto-closed I meant that I thought a close button should automatically appear if I added the data-alert attribute

Comment: Got it, nope. You'll have to add `<a class="close" href="#">×</a>` by yourself or append it with jQuery.

Comment: I think the way you assumed it work is the way it should work. Otherwise you either have to add markup directly to your HTML which is bad if JS is turned off and tedious, or progmatically add it which is just tedious. Bootstrap is supposed to take away the tedious tasks.